# Mass save records in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Please consider my Database structure in Laravel 4...

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->integer('campaign_id');
$table->string('location');
$table->string('color');
$table->string('contacts');
$table->string('pickups');
$table->string('interviews');
$table->string('guest_posts');
$table->string('book_review_opp');
```

I have a `Campaign` table/model and then the above is a `Campaign Status's` table/model that belongs to a `Campaign`.

When I create a new campaign, I have to insert 50+ records from the above table, 1 for each US state.  I also have to add all the Canadian Territories.

So when I create a record, also when I edit a campaign, I show these setting for each state with a save button.

Once a record is saved, it has to save the 50 states plus the Canada regions.

I am asking if there is a more efficient way of saving all the massive number of records at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the most efficient way to insert records is:

```
DB::table('name')->insert(<array of 50 arrays>);
```

or

```
CampaignStatus::query()->insert(<array of 50 arrays>);
```

Comment: Hello do you know if this can also work to update existing records or just to create new ones? `DB::table('name')->insert(<array of 50 arrays>);`

Answer (score 0):

You could encode the states as JSON then pull in the campaign->states column.
All you need to do is have a `$table->string('states')`, then `$campaign->states = json_encode($states_array);`

You can even set up an [accessor and mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) so that anything inserted into states is json_encode'd and then decoded when accessed